# Importing Eclipse project to Android Studio 0.8.14

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio, adt, android-gradle-plugin

I am having huge problems migrating since I am doing it on a big project.

I have: Beta 0.8.14 installed (latest version)

I generated build.gradle from eclipse and imported to android studio. I tried running it but there where no modules so after some googling I tried adding module but got an error:

```
Error:The project is using an unsupported version of Gradle.
Please point to a supported Gradle version in the project's Gradle settings or in the project's Gradle wrapper (if applicable.)
```

Tried again with gradle wrapper and this happened:

```
10:31:24 AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'appName': Already disposed: Module: 'appName'
10:31:30 AssertionError: Already disposed: Module: 'appName': Already disposed: Module: 'appName'
```

And now I am stuck.

I tried importing normal project as well (without the build.gradle file) and I got the same result. 
I don't know what I am doing wrong, I tried multiple tutorials and none worked. The project is fairly large. The reason I am migrating to android studio is to use android-support-multidex that only works with gradle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I updated android studio to 0.9.3 and it works now.